# Ranking Sets by Length of Each List and Alphabetically (If Tied) in Python

Tags: python, ranking

Is there a way to rank a multiple string sets in descending order in Python by their length and if two or more lists are tied, rank the lists alphabetically?

Let's say I am given the following lists:

```
rankings = []
general = {'hello', 'how are you', 'good', 'thanks'}
fun = {'lowkey', 'jello', 'karaoke', 'stardown', 'hilarious', 'highkey', 'drunk', 'sports'}
subjects = {'math', 'science', 'english', 'french', 'history'}
cities = {'Rome', 'NYC', 'London', 'Toronto'}
animals = {'bird', 'elephant', 'mouse', 'dog', 'cat'}
foods = {'banana', 'fish', 'meat'}
```

My expected output is:

```
rankings = ["fun", "animals", "subjects", "cities", "general", "foods"]
```

Any ideas on the basic code behind this?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say alphabetically, do you mean by the first item of the list or the name of that variable that holds the list?

Comment: The name of the variable

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use string literals for each identifier, in order to sort by identifiers as a secondary "tie-breaker".

Please refer to the "Key Functions" section in the Python docs for [sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions).

```py
all_sets = {'general': {'hello', 'how are you', 'good', 'thanks'},
            'fun': {'lowkey', 'jello', 'karaoke', 'stardown', 'hilarious', 'highkey', 'drunk', 'sports'},
            'subjects': {'math', 'science', 'english', 'french', 'history'},
            'cities': {'Rome', 'NYC', 'London', 'Toronto'},
            'animals': {'bird', 'elephant', 'mouse', 'dog', 'cat'},
            'foods': {'banana', 'fish', 'meat'}}
items = list(all_sets.items())

def sorter(dict_item):
    k, v = dict_item        # k is identifier and v is the set
    return (-len(v), k)     # sort descending by set length, ascending by identifier

sorted_items = sorted(items, key=sorter)
sorted_keys = [k for k, v in sorted_items]
```

The value of `sorted_keys` resulting:

```
['fun', 'animals', 'subjects', 'cities', 'general', 'foods']
```